# Not getting push notifications with ADHoc certificates

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, nsnotification

I am testing push notifications with production.pem with ADHoc provisioning certificates. From server side sending successfully but device is not getting notifications. Please help me

Thank you

Comment: If you are not getting notification, how could you come to know, it is sent successfully from server side?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and make it clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The Server will show success means the problem is at your side, Check the below three scenarios for this

```
1.) The gateway should be gateway.push.apple.com:2195
2.) You have refreshed your provisioning profile after creating APNS certificate
3.)Your Device Token is correct corresponding to the Distribution Provisioning profile
```

N.B If all the above things are correct,then make sure your app is in background, If your App is in foreground, then you will receive push notification, but wont be able to see it

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the Ad hoc testing of push notifications only works if the app was installed on a device without using xcode+usb cable to install the app on the device. The app has to be delivered to the phone with either TestFlight (or similar) or something else like diawi.com

Comment: I install ipa file through iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in server side.

```
List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.alert("TEST TEST",keystorePath,"test", ***true***, devices); => For Distribution 

For development => List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.alert("TEST TEST",keystorePath,"test", ***False***, devices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your device token. There are two device tokens. First one is when you run app with development other one is run app with production. These are difference. Use Ad-hoc device token.